# Why use parentheses when returning in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In the Restify framework code I found this function:

```
function queryParser(options) {

    function parseQueryString(req, res, next) {
        // Some code goes there
        return (next());
    }
    return (parseQueryString);
}
```

Why would the author write `return (next());` and `return (parseQueryString);`? Does it need parentheses there and if so, why?

Comment: It is not required. It's just a choice.

Comment: It might also being used to avoid *automatic semicolon insertion*.

Comment: Interesting post here on the topic http://jamesknelson.com/javascript-return-parenthesis/ thanks for the great question helped me learned a bunch

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't need to be that way, but it's valid JavaScript code. Actually it's quite uncommon to see such syntax. I guess it's a personal preference of the author.

Comment: @silent_coder In this specific case it's nothing for. Usually you can see parentheses used to *enclose* visually hard understandable parts of code, i.e. while using complex *ternary operators*. In the code above the parentheses could be even misleading for inexperienced developers, cause *return* in that case looks more like a *function call.*

Comment: Call me *inexperienced developer* but for a moment these parentheses caused confusion and I did a little search to figure it out as it looked exactly like a **function call** :)

Comment: This is usually syntax being carried over from C++14 where it does have an impact _or_ from old school programmers from the era when C was the popular language of its time; it was just a convention for some coders.

Comment: Never use parentheses for unary operators such as delete, typeof and void or after keywords such as return, throw as well as others (case, in or new). https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml

Answer (score 136):

Using parentheses when returning is necessary if you want to **write your return statement over several lines**.

`React.js` offers a useful example. In the return statement of the `render` property in a component you usually want to spread the JSX you return over several lines for readability reasons, e.g.:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="foo">
            <h1>Headline</h1>
            <MyComponent data={this.state.data} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Without parentheses it results in an error!

---

More generally, not using parentheses when spreading a return statement over several lines will result in an error. The following example will **execute properly**:

```js
var foo = function() {
  var x = 3;
  return (
    x 
    + 
    1
  );
};
console.log(foo());
```

Whereas the following (without the parentheses) will **throw errors**:

```js
var foo = function() {
  var x = 3;
  return 
    x 
    + 
    1
  ;
};
console.log(foo());
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Return doesn't allow statements over multiple lines natively

Comment: @Callat Sure it does allow multi-line expressions. You just must not put a linebreak right after the `return`, otherwise the expression becomes its own statement - but that's all.

Answer (score 21):

Parenthesis are used for two purposes in a return statement.

- To support multi-line expression as mentioned in @Andru Answer.
- To allow returning object in arrow function like the below:

`() => ({ name: 'Amanda' })  // Shorthand to return an object`

This is equivalent to

```
() => {
 return { name : 'Amanda' }
}
```

For more information, please check this article.
https://medium.com/@leannezhang/curly-braces-versus-parenthesis-in-reactjs-4d3ffd33128f

Comment: Great focus on the arrow function detail!

Comment: It is important to note that  in `() => ({ name: 'Amanda' }) ` the use of parenthesis is not a shortcut: the code inside curly braces is parsed as a sequence of statements

Comment: Is it allowed to use parenthesis inside curly braces wrt arrow function or either of them needs to be used ?

Answer (score 8):

```
// Create a component named MessageComponent
var MessageComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.message}</div>
    );
  }
});
```

> NOTE Why do we need the parentheses around the return statement (line
>   3)? This is because of JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion.
>   Without the parentheses, JavaScript would ignore the following lines
>   and return without a value. If the JSX starts on the same line as the
>   return, then parentheses are not needed.

Taken from [here](http://buildwithreact.com/tutorial/components).

Answer (score 2):

> Why would the author write return (next()); ... ?

Regarding `next()`:

Probably because his function is something like this:

```
function next()
{
  var i=0;
  return function (){
    // Do something with that closured i....
  }
}
```

Regarding `(xxx);`:

It is unnecessary. Every minifier will remove it.

Example (uglifyJS):

[image]

becomes:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to what others have said.

Using brackets around the return value is valid JavaScript, but mostly a bad thing to do.

Mostly bad because it doesn't add anything yet increases the size of the JavaScript which means that there is more to download to the browser. Yes most people have fast broadband connections, but don't lose sight of the fact that everything you put in the JavaScript file needs to be downloaded so avoid unnecessary code bloat. This probably doesn't matter if you use a tool to compact your code (minifier has already been mentioned), but not everyone does.

Sometimes it might aid readability. Hard pressed to think of an example in this case, but if the use of brackets makes your JavaScript clearer to you as the developer and thus easier to maintain then use them - even if it goes against what I said about code bloat.

Answer (score 1):

I tried:

```
var a = function() {
          return true || true
        }
console.log(a());

//return: true
```

```
var a = function() {
          return
              true || true
        }
console.log(a());

//return: undefined
```

```
var a = function() {
          return (
                   true || true
                 )
        }
console.log(a());

//return: true
```

Answer (score 0):

While [Andru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34643199/6433124) is popular, it is wrong that parantheses are required for multiline return statement. Here, you can see an object of foo and bar is returned with no parantheses needed.

```js
function foo () {
  return {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
  }
}
console.log(foo())
```

As long as the `return` line is not just empty space or linebreak, you can have a multiline return just fine. Otherwise [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion) takeover and break your return statement as demonstrated by Andru.

Regarding your question, I am onboard with [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20824579/6433124).

Comment: You're describing the special case of returning an object (in your code you also have to write the opening curly bracket in the same line as the `return` keyword). You are not describing the general case of returning any statement - which needs parentheses in case its spread over several lines.

Answer (score -2):

This may be old but the `return ()` can be used in this way:

```
function parseQueryString(req, res, next) {
            var id = req.param('id');
            return (id ? "Foo" : "Bar");
}
```

Less code, easy to read :)