# Is return a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, return

Apparently return can be invoked as a function?

```
function say() {
   return (
     console.log("Am"),
     console.log("I"),
     console.log("a"),
     console.log("function?")
  );
}

say();
```

Does this mean that return *is* a function?

Comment: no - it is still happening directly inside the stack of `say`, not in some new function.

Comment: No, it is a keyword. Just like ++ isn't a function but you can ++(x)

Comment: this is the syntax of return.  `,` is not `;` this is an expression not a statement.

Comment: Related question: [Why use parentheses when returning in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20824558/877472)

Comment: you can put anything between parenthesis. `(a = 2)`. `a = (2)` `(a) = 32`

Comment: @nicael: that is because of what parenthesis do in JS, and the fact that you don't actually expect any return from this function. The return word is not useful here (see the linked question above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword "return" is not a function. The documentations says that return is a statement.

The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.

That means

```
(
     console.log("Am"),
     console.log("I"),
     console.log("a"),
     console.log("function?")
```

)

is evaluated as an expression and the result of this expression is returned from the `say()` function. The parentheses only group the four calls to `console.log` together. The commas serve to separate the function calls within the expression.

The this expression will return the value returned from the last element in the list, which in this case is `console.log("function?")`. And the function `console.log` returns undefined.

So the function `say()` would return `undefined`.