# Why do we have to use parenthesis with return, in react native

Tags: react-native

I saw a react native tutorial and when return something, it used parenthesis. Why do we have to include parenthesis while returning?

```
return (
    <Modal>
      <View>
        <Image
          source={props.selectedPlace ? props.selectedPlace.placeImage : null}
        />
        <Text>{props.selectedPlace.PlaceName}</Text>
        <View>
          <Button />
          <Button />
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use parentheses when returning in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824558/why-use-parentheses-when-returning-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a javascript language property
Parenthesis are needed if you want to write your return statement over several lines.

[Here the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

> The return statement is affected by automatic semicolon insertion
>   (ASI). No line terminator is allowed between the return keyword and
>   the expression.
>
> [...]
>
> To avoid this problem (to prevent ASI), you
>   could use parentheses:
>
> return (
>
> a + b
>
> );