# Can't access this object due to complex js function - Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this, arrow-functions, ellipsis

I'm working with the popular vue-select component for a VueJs project. I want to customize a keyDownEvent and looked into the docs to see how to achieve this. I was met with a cryptic example using a combination of modern JS techniques.

```
<template>
  <v-select
          taggable
          multiple
          no-drop
          :map-keydown="handlers"
          placeholder="enter an email"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CustomHandlers',
  data: {
      variableIwantAccessTo: []
  },
  methods: {
    handlers: (map, vm) => ({
      ...map, 50: e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if( e.key === '@' && vm.search.length > 0 ) {
          vm.search = `${vm.search}@gmail.com`;
        }
      },
    }),
  },
};
</script>
```

I understand the simple logic within the if block, but I do not understand the combination of techniques used that leads up to it. The main issue I'm having with my custom implementation is losing the context for the **this** object. I want something like this:

```
    handlers: (map, vm) => ({
  ...map, 50: e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if( e.key === '@' && vm.search.length > 0 ) {
      console.log(this.variableIwantAccessTo);
    }
  },
```

I cannot figure out how to pass it down with this implementation.
Here's a ref to the docs: https://vue-select.org/guide/keydown.html#mapkeydown

Comment: Oh, `vm` is not the Vue instance as I thought. You'd have to change `handler: (map, vm) => ({/*...*/})` to `handler(map, vm) { return {/*...*/} }`, where you'd be able to use `this` as the Vue instance.

Comment: I tried this with Eason Yus answers and it registers as undefined even immediately at the start of the first arrow function.

Comment: I can't help without seeing the code you've tried. Here's a working demo as I described: https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ExgPEKV

Comment: Ah yes, this is how I'd prefer it written as well. I actually just solved it myself right before your post by using function() {} rather than arrow notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you see ,there're actually two level of functions in the case,the original style of handler function omit {}, so you don't have a place to define a self(reference to this) in the outer function.

in vue component , this in the outer one will point to the component,so we declare self here, then we use self as a closure variance in the inner one.

i guess this will do your trick, try it ,please.

```
export default {
  name: 'CustomHandlers',
  methods: {
    // handlers: (map, vm) => {
    // if it is arrow function,it can't do the trick 
    // thanks to  Yair Cohen
       handlers(map, vm) {
        const self = this;
        return {
          ...map, 50: e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if( e.key === '@' && vm.search.length > 0 ) {
              vm.search = `${vm.search}@gmail.com`;
              // self will be this here
              const self2 = self;
            }
          },
        };
    },
  },
};
```

update: code changed ,outer function from arrow function to normall function,

Comment: This is still not going to work as the handlers function is an arrow function instead of a regular so this is still undefined there. If you change it to regular function it'll work

Comment: yeah you're right, i just made a demo to test my code, i'll edit it in case wrongly guide others.

Comment: Shoutout to @YairCohen for breaking down the function and tony19 for providing a working example using 'this'. I eventually came to the result myself after using this answer and recently dealing with this problem on another project. For those who don't already know checkout this section in the docs https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down that function:

1. You are declaring an arrow function called `handlers` that accepts two arguments named `map` and `vm`.

The reason you are losing context is because you are using an arrow function as a method, if you change that arrow function to a regular function you'll be able to access `this`.

With that being said it seems like it's designed this way on purpose, and from looking at the code I can assume that you should pass the context as the second argument - `vm`.

2. You are returning an object: in the first part of the object you are using the spread operator to spread the `map` argument, from this we can assume that `map` is also an object and you want to return an object that contains the object map itself. (by using the spread operator, you are essentially merging `map` into the object you're returning.

The second part of the object you're returning is a property with the name `50`, this property is a method which receives an event, calls `preventDefault()` on that event, then has an if statement, if that if statement passes it assigns `vm.search` to a certain value.

Since we assumed that `vm` stands for the context, this is the same as assigning `this.search` so it's essentially assigning a variable in the context a particular value.

Hope that's more clear now :)

Comment: Technically, you don't need `this` in an event handler. The element `this` would usually point to is available from the event object that's passed in.

Comment: Only if it's a regular function, with an arrow function this will be equal to the this value from the enclosing scope, which in this case is still undefined.

Comment: Well, yeah, the `this` you get in an arrow function is whatever happens to be inherited from context, if it happened to exist. My point is: Don't use `this` in an event handler; use the event object. There's no need to switch to a regular function.

Comment: @YairCohen Am I right in thinking there's also a self-invoking function after the first arrow function? Why is it wrapped with ()?

And ordinarily I'd agree with the intentions of Ouroborus, but the vm object is not the object I want. I'm trying to reference a variable in the parent scope on the Vue instance itself, written as 'this.vairableName'.

Comment: No there is no self-invoking function after the first arrow function, the parentheses are there because that's how you return an expression with multiple lines. Check this out for more examples on how that works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824558/why-use-parentheses-when-returning-in-javascript

Comment: @YairCohen Not exactly. Rather, it's the arrow function's implicit return for an *object literal*. The object needs to be wrapped in parentheses so the parser can distinguish it from a *block statement*.

Comment: @tony19 Right, that's more accurate.